# "Disk Not Found" Error when trying to install iso image of CentOs on ESXI using VSphere

Tags: centos, vmware-esxi

When trying to install CentOs setup as an iso image on datastore, i get an error :
"Disk Not Found". I am using ESXi 4.1 as host VM. Is there a way to attach DVD/CD as iso image ?
I tried "Connect at Power on" Checked and Connect CD/DVD on the VSphere Console, but i still am unable ot get the iso image recognized as a DVD mounted image

Comment: And you copied this from your local machine to the datastore using the VSClient's datastore browser upload link right? What VM machine model is your VM (4, 7)? I've done this very operation before and it's gone smoothly, have you checked your .iso file?

Comment: Sounds like its booting to the empty partition instead of the CD. Did you tell the bios to boot from the CD/DVD?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too specific to the OP's particular use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

if i look at the image size, it was 11 MB, so it WAS a boot iso, but nithing else, if we compare it with other boot images with complete iso's therein lies the solution. This boot.iso was from rBUILD/Conary packaging

Comment: If this is solved, please mark it as solved by clicking the tick mark at the left so that it turns solid green. This is how you mark a question as solved on our sites.